# How do I email a recruiter after he mentioned he will be in touch for an online interview, but I still haven't received an email from him?

Tags: hiring-process

I recently applied for a position which closed.

I received an email 3 days later from an interviewer last week who asked about my rights to work in the country where the position was based. After I confirmed that I had the right to work in the country, he mentioned that he would be in contact soon for an online interview.

I then noticed after that email was sent, the position was re-advertised the next day (I assume due to the lack of applicants holding the working rights for the country where the application is based).  The re-advertising of the position has been closed 3 days after that.

It has been a further 3 days since then.

How do I send him an email, asking him when the Skype interview would take place?

I was thinking something along the lines of (Would greatly appreciate your amendments!):

> Dear ****,
>
> I hope you had a good weekend! Thank you again for the potential
>   opportunity to work at ******.
>
> I’m really looking forward to chatting with you.  I noticed that the
>   position was recently re-advertised, and would love to demonstrate my
>   suitability for the position.  Just thought I would let you know that
>   a few good times for me are ******, ******, and ******.
>
> Thanks and I look forward to hearing from you soon.
>
> Best, ******

Comment: Can you please update your question to include timeframes.

Comment: I've changed the times to remove dates and instead use relative time. This means the question ages a little better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a read, and it looks like it has only been a week!

I wouldn't read too much into the opening and closing of the advertisements. I don't think anyone in their right mind would advertise a position for only 3 days. More likely that there are automated systems at play that are causing the advertisements to appear and disappear.

I would personally give them another week before sending a follow up.

If you do get in contact with them, I would avoid letting them know you're keeping an eye on the job postings. It seems a little desperate.

In addition, I would avoid mentioning when good times for you are. Let them ask you before you nominate times.

Comment: Good Point!  I'll give it a bit of time and wait to hear back from them.  I think I'm just a bit worried as the application wasn't done through an ATS (Applicant tracking system), but was actually advertised manually on LinkedIn, and we had to email in our applications.

Could you suggest how I should word my email to them if I didn't hear back from them in the end?  Thanks again!